# Tomcat & Maven installed correctly but don't see my local

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I've set up tomcat & maven in eclipse. I've followed all the proper instructions. When I start the server, it starts & runs successfully. Maven Build is working fine as well. I open localhost:8080 and it says if you see this apache has been installed correctly. Now the thing is that I want to see my local running in place of localhost:8080. I don't know why it 404's.

Can some one tell me what should I be doing exactly? server.xml looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you have any application deployed in the `webapps` folder, you have to check that.

Comment: Yes I do. Lots of applications. What about that?

Comment: Try then going to one of these applications using their context root as well in the url

Comment: din't get you. can you simplify? I'm doing it for the first time

Comment: Say you had a web application deployed e.g. with context root HelloWorld then you could get to it using localhost:8080/HelloWorld

Comment: In webapp I have like webinf ,assets , metainf .. I want to see my local page with my domain name to open. do I need to do something in server.xml or pom.xml? Like change the port or something like that? I use varnish as well

Comment: Say we have a `sample`application in tomcat-(some verions)/webapps/sample....then you can try localhost:8080/sample....but the webinf, assets, metainf don't look to me like application folders. By default localhost:8080/your-application should be good to work if you have your war file placed in the webapps.

Comment: yeah I don't want to run a particular file. I want to run the whole application.

Comment: Try changing the port number to for example 8088. Also take into account maybe the default application which is suppose to be on localhost:8080 is removed. Another make sure your browser is not using proxy settings.

Comment: change the port number in server.xml right? And by the way, thanks for your responses. Appreciate it

Comment: Yeah in conf/server.xml.

Comment: I can actually see the apache successfully installed page when I hit mydomainname:8080 . But I dont see my local page under that domain name

Comment: Oke then you don't have issue with port and you don't have to change the port. The domain name you have to change your hosts file. Are you using Windows or Linux based OS? I mean you have to add `127.0.0.1  mydomainname` in your host file.

Comment: In Windows 7 `hosts` is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Comment: In my host file I've mapped my IP to my domain name . That's wrong?

Comment: Your tomcat is running on localhost (127.0.0.1), right? So it would not make sense to map it to your IP address. You should map it to the IP of the Tomcat server. Unless you wanted to access it remotely or something.

Comment: yeah but mapping 127.0.0.1 mydomainname gives me the same page "installation successfull page" as before. I can't see my local homepage.

Comment: Otherwise you have to change the IP address it is bound in your server.xml to your IP but Iam not sure if that's what you want. Where is your local homepage located?

Comment: yeah that's what I want

Comment: In the server.xml connector you can set the IP address here `address="127.0.0.1"`

Comment: I don't see address= anywhere

Comment: Which is your Tomcat version? It should be here or you can add it if it is missing `<Connector name="connector" address="127.0.0.1" port="8080"....` it is the attribute `address`you need to add if missing.

Comment: doesnot wok. It'stomcat 7

Comment: Don't forget to add `useIPVHosts="true"` to allow ip based access for tomcat too.

Comment: nothing worked. I just don't understand whats wrong. My maven works fine.  Tomcat is installed properly . I just dont see helloworld. on mydomainname:8080 when I should see hellowoorld. I dont get whats wrong